# How to get mobile location with pi

Tags: pi-3

Is it possible to get mobile locations with the help of pi. Distance matters here for me. All i want is to get my team's mobile's live location from portable pi device.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is confusing, do you want location or distance?

Comment: Are there not a selection of mobile tracking apps available without having to use a Pi (or anything else for that matter)? The question feels a little off topic to me, unless it's the location of the Pi you want to track?

Comment: In simple words i wanna track the mobile phone with the help of pi...

Comment: distance in a sense of area that if mobile enters in that area i get the message.

Answer (score 1):

Do a web search for "geolocation using raspberry pi".

There are many options (including "how to" articles & tutorials on the web).  You can use a GPS (there are numerous GPS hats/shields for the Pi) but these don't work inside buildings (GPS needs a view of the sky).  There are non-GPS solutions which use WiFi & cell-tower locations to estimate location.

The search terms suggested above should give you what you want.